# User auth with "remember me"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

This is a **multi-part question**, so feel free to give input on any one of the parts, but since I can only accept one answer, I will accept the most complete answer in relation to all that is being asked. I will upvote partial answers if they are relevant and useful.

First, a little background, without going TL;DR on the question: I am using [Quake Framework](https://github.com/clowerweb/Quake-Framework) (yes, it's mine) for this project - to quickly describe it, it uses **CodeIgniter** and **jQuery 1.8.0** mainly (among others, but they are irrelevant for the question.) It also includes the Total Storage jQuery plugin (for local storage) and jQuery Cookies as a fallback for browsers that don't support local storage.

**Part 1:**

I have built a user authentication system. The login has a "remember me" feature (which is not yet functional) - what is the best way to store the user's data? Some thoughts:

- Store the username and sha1'd password in local storage/cookie. This seems to me to be a possibly insecure option, but I'm unsure.
- Store some kind of hash (maybe PHP's `com_create_guid()`?) in the localstorage/cookie as well as in the database (maybe along with a date for expiry?)

**Part 2:**

After implementation of the "remember me" feature, what is the best way to finish implementing it? Should I have every page check for the cookie (because the user could initially hit any page and would need re-logged?) While each page of course needs to check the session, and once they are re-logged by the cookie/local storage, they will get a regular session, it seems very redundant to check for both a session and a cookie on each page (we'd of course first check for a session so that we don't check cookies of logged-in users repeatedly, and then check for the cookie if there's no session, but still.) Is there a better way?

Comment: How are you storing passwords in your database? You should be storing them in such a way that exposing them to the user (for example, through a cookie) would not give away any information.

Comment: @arxanas They are stored in the database as SHA1 + a hardcoded key in CodeIgniter using `do_hash`. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/security_helper.html - This uses both SHA1 and the custom assigned encryption key. I am thinking of storing the username and CI encrypted password in a cookie (local storage when supported), but I'm not sure if this would be secure?

Comment: It would be, but `SHA1` has been generally accepted as not as good as solutions like `bcrypt`. While this probably won't an issue unless you have a massive client base, you should keep it in mind. If you don't feel like using cookies, you can just use sessions and keep the data out of the reach of the user.

Comment: @arxanas is there a way to keep persistent sessions if the user checks "remember me" and comes back, say, a week later?

Comment: i have a code in pure javascript for the functioning of 'remember me'. wanna try?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Well, normally I would, except that I'm using the Total Storage jQuery plugin which uses local storage where available and cookies as a fallback in browsers that don't support local storage. Right now, I'm already storing the username and encrypted password in local storage (the site is not production, so don't worry), but I think I need to swap this for using a GUID instead, which is mostly on the PHP side anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1

It would be best to generate a random token(hash you mentioned) in the server, and save it both in the DB and cookie. Making it random will prevent others from "guessing" or generating your token. Using a GUID would be your best option.

Part 2

In each page, you can check if a session exists. If no session is available, check for your auth cookie. If auth cookie is available, trigger your auth-check code. That way, you only need to check the auth cookie when user is not logged in already.

Comment: So generating a GUID is more secure than storing the username (in plain text) and hashed password (SHA1 + key) in a cookie? Is the GUID guaranteed to be unique? Is `com_create_guid()` the correct way? Sorry for having so many questions in one comment...

Comment: GUID is definitely more secure. As a general rule, never store any passwords in the client, even encrypted. com_create_guid() would work fine. There is also a PEAR UUID package you can consider http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid

Comment: So I would store the username and this GUID in a cookie, along with the GUID in the database, and I'm assuming there should be an expiry date set in the db so that the GUID is only good for a certain time, or should I not worry about that? I'm leaning towards not worrying about a date, but I'm not really sure what the best practice is.

Comment: The expiry part depends on your requirement. If you don't want the user to be logged out ever, you need not store an expiry. Else have it stored in the DB along with the GUID token.